# MySQL do INNER JOIN if specific value is 1

Tags: mysql, sql

I have this query:

```
SELECT 
    e.*, u.name AS event_creator_name 
FROM `edu_events` e 
    LEFT JOIN `edu_users` u 
        ON u.user_id = e.event_creator 
    INNER JOIN `edu_event_participants` 
        ON participant_event = e.event_id && participant_user = 1 
WHERE 
    MONTH(e.event_date_start) = 6 
    AND YEAR(e.event_date_start) = 2013
```

It works perfect, however, I only want to do the INNER JOIN if the value: e.event_type equals 1. If not, it should ignore the INNER JOIN.

I have tried for some time to figure it out, but the solutions seems difficult to implment for my proposes (as it is only for select/specific values).

I'm thinking about something like:

```
SELECT 
    e.*, u.name AS event_creator_name 
FROM `edu_events` e 
    LEFT JOIN `edu_users` u ON u.user_id = e.event_creator

if(e.event_type == 1) {
    INNER JOIN `edu_event_participants` ON participant_event = e.event_id && participant_user = 1 
}

WHERE MONTH(e.event_date_start) = 6 
AND YEAR(e.event_date_start) = 2013
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly you only want the results where there is an entry on edu_event_participants with the same event_id and participant_user = 1 but only if event_type = 1, but you don't really want to get any information from the edu_event_participants table. If that is the case:

```
SELECT 
    e.*, u.name AS event_creator_name 
FROM `edu_events` e 
    LEFT JOIN `edu_users` u 
        ON u.user_id = e.event_creator 
WHERE 
    -- as Simon at mso.net suggested
    WHERE e.event_date_start BETWEEN DATE('2013-06-01') AND DATE('2013-07-01')
    -- MONTH(e.event_date_start) = 6 
    -- AND YEAR(e.event_date_start) = 2013
    AND (
        -- either event is public
        e.event_type = 1 or
        -- or the user is in the participants table
        exists
            (select 1 from `edu_event_participants` 
            where participant_event = e.event_id
            AND participant_user = 1)
    )
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, and for the date correction. However I dont think i got to be clear enough in my question. Please read the comment for  @simon.

Comment: ok, so either event type is 1 (public event) or the user was invited (exists in the participants table). i just changed the "<> 1" to a "= 1" and it should do it.

Comment: It doesn't work. It compiles the query, but prints nothing. If it helps, here is my table structure: [edu_events](http://cl.ly/image/3q3s2d1v3z1W) and [edu_event_participants](http://cl.ly/image/2d26171v2U1d)

Comment: the event_date_start in the data you show is 2012-07-09, so it gets excluded from the query... do you have any rows with a event_date_start in May?

Answer (score 1):

I have edited the below following further feedback from @Matthias

```
-- This will get all events for a given user plus all globals
SELECT 
    e.*, 
    u.name AS event_creator_name 
FROM `edu_users` u 

-- in the events
INNER JOIN `edu_events` e 
    ON (
        -- Get all the ones that the user is participant
        e.event_creator = u.user_id
        -- Or where event_type is 1
        OR 
        e.event_type = 1
    )
    AND e.event_date_start BETWEEN DATE('2013-06-01') AND DATE('2013-07-01')
    
-- Add in event participants even though it doesn't seem to be used?
INNER JOIN `edu_event_participants` AS eep 
    ON eep.participant_event = e.event_id
    AND eep.participant_user = 1
    
-- Add the user ID into the WHERE
WHERE u.user_id = 1;
```

This just might not make too much sence as it feels as though edu_event_participants has too much information in.  event_creator should really be stored against the event itself, and then event_participants just containing an event id, user id, and user type.

If you are looking to get all users on an event, it may be better to do a seperate query for that event to select all users based off an event_id

The note on your use of MONTH() and YEAR().  This will trigger a table scan, as MySQL will need to apply the MONTH() and YEAR() functions to all rows to determine which match that WHERE statement.  If you instead calculate the upper and lower limits (i.e. `2013-06-01 00:00:00 <= e.event_date_start < 2013-07-01 00:00:00`) then MySQL can use a far more efficient range scan on an index (assuming one exists on e.event_date_start)

Comment: Thank you very much for the tip on the daterange. I will implent this. However, I dont think I got to clear enough in my question. The table edu_event_participants is a table of data which tells which EVENTS the user has been invited to. So if the user is invited to this event, it has to be shown. But if e.event_type is "1" it means that the event is public and everybody can see it. So basically I want to show all events where type = 1 AND the events to which the user has been invited to. I wish I could UP your answer, but dont have enough rep, and can't figure out how to get the 15 points.

Comment: That makes more sense - in that case you can rearrange the query :)  Will edit my answer

Comment: Hi Simon! Thank you very much for your answer. I tried to test out the SQL query your provided, however, it gives me the error: `#1054 - Unknown column 'e.event_creator' in 'on clause'`. It seems as you don't fully know the table structure, logically, because I didn't post it. But here it is, if it helps: [edu_events](http://cl.ly/image/3q3s2d1v3z1W) and [edu_event_participants](http://cl.ly/image/2d26171v2U1d)

Comment: I have managed to fix it like so: **SELECT e.*, u.name AS event_creator_name, ep.participant_user AS invited FROM `edu_events` e LEFT JOIN `edu_users` u ON u.user_id = e.event_creator LEFT JOIN `edu_event_participants` ep ON participant_event = e.event_id && participant_user = 1 AND e.event_type = 0 WHERE MONTH(e.event_date_start) = 6 AND YEAR(e.event_date_start) = 2013** and then sort the array with PHP like this: `if($row['invited'] OR $row['event_type'] == 1) { // if current user is invited, or event is public`. Isn't that efficient enough?

Comment: Well you are still using MONTH() and YEAR which is still going to cause a table scan.  Additionally you are selecting rows you don't want to use. Both of these behaviors are not as efficient as they could be, and can be optimised by a rearranged SELECT.  I have updated the SELECT, that error was a pre-coffee mistake on my part.  The above should now operate as specified

Comment: Thanks again. We do use the edu_event_participants. This table tells which users have been invited to specific events. That means, that it should only get the event if the specific user (our case: 1) is invited to the event -OR- if the event is public. So that's what edu_event_participants does. The "event_creator" simply tells which user created the specific event.

Comment: jvilhena's solution worked. Thank you very much for your intense help though!

Comment: No worries.  For the sake of optimisation, make sure to change the date limiting though as already detailed - it will have a big difference as the size of your tables increases.  All in all I prefer to do it in a single query where viable though as it helps reduce any maintenance overhead as there is less redundant logic :)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe what you're after is displaying the left table value even if there's no matching data from right table? On that case you can use outer join like so:

```
LEFT OUTER JOIN `edu_event_participants` ON participant_event = e.event_id && participant_user = 1 AND e.event_type = 1
```

Comment: Thanks, I have tried this, but it doesn't seem to work. It simply prints all, and I only want to show the ones to which are public (type = 1) AND the events which the current user has been invited to.

Comment: Hmm in that case try INNER JOIN instead

Comment: If I do that, it will only print the events which the user has been inivited to. That is alright; but I also want to fetch the events where event_type equals = 1 (1: visible to all - 0: only invited)